# First time beta owner please help

Tags: health, fish

I have a male beta for a month now.he was in a small tank and was just upgraded to a tl2 gallon tank with a filter and I also added a heater.i knew he was unhappy in the cold dirty tank he was in so when I got the new tank I was anxious and added him in the new tank within ten minutes of setting it up.i didn't know you wernt suppose to do that.i have never owned a fish.he was very happy the first day but now he is not eating and he is literally laying at the bottom of the tank.his color is also very dull.i am afraid I am slowly killing him because of adding him to the new tank so quickly.i don't know when or how much I should change this water but all I know is my fishy is not ok.could I of put him on the path of death.?? Please help anyone... thank you

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange! Handily, your question has already been asked and answered. You may wish to read [ask] and [use the search](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfish%5D+betta+bottom) to find similar questions.

Comment: No one answered if I can kill my fish because I added him to a new tank the same day and didn't wait 24 to 48 hours before adding him

Comment: That question tells you what you need to know. Look at [my answer here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/17956/6826) which explains how to monitor your water quality. 24 hours and 48 hours are still very low times to add a fish. You will want to read about [the nitrogen cycle](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/19351/6826). You can [join us in the chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box) to discuss more issues!