# My betta fish is now lying on the down of my bottle

Tags: fish, betta

[image]my betta fish is not eating anything and he is lying on the down of my bottle and becoming inactive day by day and found some black spots on his fins

Comment: A bottle is not an adequate home for any fish. A betta requires heat and filtration for success.

Comment: First one month he were enjoying it

Comment: I've marked your question as a duplicate. It will give you some tips on how best to look after your fish. I've written an answer on this myself too: https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/17956/6826. (Also, welcome to Pets StackExchange :) )